# Facebook library login dialog how to modify its appearance?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the facebook library in order to login I call this method:

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions
                                allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                           completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

If the allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI parameter is set to yes the facebook login dialog is shown in full screen. Is there any way to change that and have the login dialog appear not in full screen? I would like it to just appear on foreground and take most of the screen size but not full screen.

I've seen this done but I would like to know if it is possible with the current facebook library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you are allowed to modify the login UI. I have seen devs getting rejected for modifying other aspects of the facebook SDK UI bundle (namely the login button) but this was clearly not acceptable.

My best guess is to set allowUI to no, and sort of mimic your own interface.

Although, from a UX perspective, I would prefer you kept it in the style defined by the FB SDK.

Comment: my main issue is that I don't want the user to get the feeling that he is leaving the app. I don't want to change the style of the ui, just to make it appear like an alert view - on foreground and my app to be visible behind it.

Comment: Well, the single signon SDK has a very discreet UI for iOS 6.0, but I have yet to find a way to avoid a trip to a facebook UI if the user is not using facebook single signon.